# Get parent form name value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, showdialog, owner

Hi I have a form which is called by several other forms via the 'showdialog()' command
I'd like it to do different things depending on which form it's called from

so I need to get the name of the parent form.
I try with Me.Parent.Name or Me.Owner.Name I always get nothing value.

how can I get the form father that called the showdialog command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parent. That is only relevant for child controls. If you add a `Button` to a form, the form is the parent of the `Button`. Your form, like most, is a top-level window, so it has no parent.

There is no owner unless you specify one. The way to do that is to pass the owner when you call `ShowDialog`, i.e.

```vb
Using dialogue As New DialogueForm
    dialogue.ShowDialog(Me)
End Using
```

The dialogue will then be able to access the calling form via its `Owner` property.

Note that you shouldn't be interested in the `Name` of the owner but rather its type, e.g.

```vb
Dim ownerType = Owner.GetType()

If ownerType Is GetType(Form1) Then
    '...
End If
```

Comment: How can i pass Form1..Form2..Form3 variable to datagridview?

Dim ownerType = Owner.GetType()
                    Dim id As Integer = ownerType.name.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

Comment: @GuidoM., the comments for the answer is not the place to ask a new question. If you have a question, post a new question.